# Set breakpoint at function inside dll in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I want to set a breakpoint at a specific function that's located in a dll. The pdb's are public so I know the function name (say `namespace1::namespace2::className::functionName`), but no sources.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio?

I've tried "Breakpoints -> New -> Break at function". I wouldn't be asking had that worked. :)

Comment: Did you try to set the breakpoint after the DLL was loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void wrapper_func(parameters...){
    // call the real function
    std::cout<<"before call dll func"<<std::endl;
    namespace1::namespace2::className::functionName(parameters...);
    std::cout<<"after call dll func"<<std::endl;
}
```

then set breakpoint on wrapper_func.but you need to do some work to call the wrapper func instead of the dll func.

### another way is set  breakpoint on function address

> If you don’t like to load the NT symbols, there is another method
>   Get the relative address of the function in which you want to set breakpoint with some PE tools. For example, just type “dumpbin /exports C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll” in the Visual Studio command line, you can get “RVA” of each exported symbol in “user32.dll”. For instance, “RVA” of “GetMessageW” is “000091C6”.
>
> Now check the image base of “user32.dll” in the VS debugger’s “Modules” windows, the values is “7E410000” on my laptop (Generally, the system dlls would not be relocated, so the image base value here is equal to the value written in PE file). Then the starting address of “GetMessageW” is “7E410000+000091C6= 7E4191C6”. Just set a function breakpoint at this address. Then the debugger will stop when calling into “GetMessageW”

[see this bolg](https://wyfeizj.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-windows-api-function/)

Comment: That's not an option, functionName is called internally from that and other dll's.

Comment: found [this](https://wyfeizj.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-windows-api-function/) from google,hope it helped

Comment: @chenjun add that to the answer (not just the link, also text), second point there is definitely the way to do it

Comment: @chenjun that's exactly what I did, was about to update this question later. If you post that I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Source Code Files which contains the function which you want to debug. `pdb files` has information/directions to get you to function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database

Comment: No, you don't need the source files. See chenjun's comment (hopefully an answer soon)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: So you just wanted the program control to stop at a  function insize DLL. Have not tried the things mentioned in blog, but do you expect to debug the Source Code of the function as well? Also after you performed things mentioned in blog, are you able to see the Actual Source Code Lines (i guess you cannot). Please update.